# Catalyst Control Center removal

Tags: windows, windows-vista, uninstall, graphics, amd-catalyst

I've recently tested a graphics card on a machine that required different drivers than my onboard integrated graphics, so I had catalyst control center installed.

After I pulled out the graphics card and went back to using the onboard graphics, I deleted the catalyst center through control panel -> programs.. which was fine.

But apparently it didn't really remove it. it doesn't show up under programs anymore
but when I reboot windows I get an error saying "The catalyst Control Center is not supported by the driver version of your enabled graphics adapter" and its still in the process bar...

how do I permanently remove it?

Comment: did you try re-install and than re-uninstalling? Also please do provide windows version and architecture.

Comment: its a windows vista 32bit work computer

and that didn't work.. grrr.. its annoyning cause it told me everything was fine, I reinstalled the catalyst center..
then I did a completely removal and it asked if I wanted to remove the catalyst center aswell.. I ofc selected that option and it uninstalled and closed the program and told me it was done with succes

now I boot up its back in the processbar.. and its telling me again that I don't have a card that supports the catalyst center

Comment: Is your onboard integrated graphics 'card' also ATI?

Answer (score 0):

I've read [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Operating-Systems/How-to-uninstall-Catalyst-Control-Centre-and-ATI-Catalyst/td-p/155588) about '[Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revosetup.exe)' which may help you. Failing that there are other instructions [here](http://www.tweaktown.com/articles/569/ati_catalyst_installation_guide/index2.html) regarding manually removing the Catalyst drivers and registry entries after uninstalling.

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2438651/) is a Microsoft install/uninstall troubleshooter which may also work. Goodluck!